# Simple property of power of -1

Tags: arithmetic

Is $(-1)^{a+b} = (-1)^{a-b}$ true $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ ?

My argument:
$$
(-1)^{a-b} = \frac{(-1)^a}{(-1)^b}
= \frac{(-1)^a}{(-1)^b}.\frac{(-1)^b}{(-1)^b}
= \frac{(-1)^{a+b}}{(-1)^{2b}}
= \frac{(-1)^{a+b}}{1}
= (-1)^{a+b}
$$

Any flaw?

Comment: First of all, usually $(-1)^a \neq -1^a$. Fix that.

Comment: @adjan I think he works with $(-1)^{a-b}$. It seems to be right...

Comment: @PiotrBenedysiuk yes, that was a notation advice.

Comment: @adjan corrected

Comment: Make it shorter: $(-1)^{a-b}=(-1)^{a-b}(-1)^{2b}=(-1)^{a+b}$. (Or $a+b$ and $a-b$ have the same parity.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, no flaw. (apart from your lack of parentheses, that's confusing). We know that $(-1)^k$ is $1$ when $k$ is even, and $-1$ when $k$ is odd. And it's trivial that $a-b\equiv a+b\mod 2$.

Comment: Well, not working in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ though. Or may be I am not understanding the connection?

Comment: What part is not working in $\mathbb{Z}_2$? The exponents work $\mod 2$

Comment: I mean that $a,b$ are from $\mathbb{Z}$, not from $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Also, +1, -1 is not in modulo 2

Comment: I know $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$, but only their value $\mod 2$ matters for the value $(-1)^a$ and $(-1)^b$. And actually, $-1\equiv 1\mod 2$

Comment: I see, since whole of $\mathbb{Z}$ can be partitioned into odd, even partition classes, $mod 2$. And $a-b$, $a+b$ have same parity in $mod 2$, therefore -1 raised to powers of same parity will give equal answer.

Comment: Yes, you're completely right. That was the point I was trying to get across